# Scrolling ListView causes app to crash

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a `ListView` which I'm populating from a SQLite database. I have 350 rows in my `ListView` on my HTC Hero 2.1 and everything works fine. I installed it on Samsung Galaxy S 2.2 and I have 270 rows in my `ListView`, and every time when I reach near the bottom of my `ListView` scrolling the list, my app crashes.

This is the log file:

```
06-17 14:29:33.796 W/dalvikvm( 3565): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at aec.phonebook.ListContacts$ItemAdapter.getView(ListContacts.java:539)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1410)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1802)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:727)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:698)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3367)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at   android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2251)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3605)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3819)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1723)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1129)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1810)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-17 14:29:33.816 E/AndroidRuntime( 3565):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 14:29:33.827 W/ActivityManager( 2465):   Force finishing activity aec.phonebook/.ListContacts
06-17 14:29:33.831 I/        ( 2465): dumpmesg > "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.log"
06-17 14:29:33.855 I/dumpstate( 3830): begin
06-17 14:29:33.890 V/InputDevice( 2465): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
06-17 14:29:36.890 W/PowerManagerService( 2465): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
06-17 14:29:36.890 I/PowerManagerService( 2465): Ulight 7->3|0
06-17 14:29:36.929 D/VoldCmdListener( 2348): asec list
06-17 14:29:36.937 D/VoldCmdListener( 2348): CommandListener::AsecCmd::runCommand -> com.fridgecat.android.atiltlite-1 
06-17 14:29:38.222 I/dumpstate( 3830): done
06-17 14:29:38.370 W/WindowManager( 2465): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
06-17 14:29:38.374 W/ActivityManager( 2465): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4806e860 aec.phonebook/.ListContacts}
```

EDIT:

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    Item j = items.get(position);

    if (j != null) {
        TextView tvn = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView tvnum = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
        TextView tvid = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        TextView tvoper = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewOperator);

        if (tvn != null) {
            tvn.setText(j.getname());                           
        }
        if(tvnum != null){
            tvnum.setText(j.getnumber());
        }
        if (tvid != null) {
            tvid.setText(j.getid());                       
        }
        if(tvoper != null){
            tvoper.setText(j.getoperator());

            if(j.getstatus().equals("0")){
                tvoper.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            if(j.getstatus().equals("1")){
                tvoper.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            if(j.getstatus().equals("2")){
                tvoper.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There has to be crash log. Inspect your logs carefully.

Comment: What on this line: `at aec.phonebook.ListContacts$ItemAdapter.getView(ListContacts.java:539)` could be null?  Debug your app and fix it and you'll find your answer.

Comment: @Chris cant figure out why on HTC hero 2.1 works fine? what can cause the problem? i'm totally confused

Comment: @op can't figure it out either without knowing what's on that line.

Comment: @Chris i EDIT my post with the getView method can u tell me what can cause here to crash on 2.2. The app crash only when i scroll the listview to the near bottom of the list

Comment: Ok now which line in the code is line 539?  It looks like you're being careful to check nulls so I'm guessing the issue is with your Item array or the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Might be the possible error in your code is "string array size"  that you have defined .

for example : The StringArray you created ,has 270 elements but size you have defined maybe more than 270 .
that creates problem , of null values in the remaining uninitialised arrays.

So make sure the ArraySize is equal to your ListSize ..

Hope it helps